# Save a squared thumbnail of uploaded image file in PHP

Tags: php, thumbnails

I am attempting to create and save a squared version (thumb) of an uploaded image file with php. My current script crops it as it should, but the image is completely black. Here is my code:

```
if ($_FILES['profile_pic']['type'] == "image/png") {
                            $is_image = true;
                            $newImage = imagecreatefrompng($img);
                        } else if ($_FILES['profile_pic']['type'] == "image/jpeg") {
                            $is_image = true;
                            $newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
                        } else if ($_FILES['profile_pic']['type'] == "image/gif") {
                            $is_image = true;
                            $newImage = imagecreatefromgif($img);
                        } else {
                            $is_image = false;
                        }
                        $img         = $_FILES["profile_pic"]['tmp_name'];
                        $min_width   = 100;
                        $min_height  = 100;
                        $width       = 0;
                        $height      = 0;
                        if ($is_image) {
                            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);
                        }

                        if ($is_image && $height >= $min_height && $width >= $min_width) {
                            $img         = $_FILES["profile_pic"]['tmp_name'];
                            $imgPath     = "../img/profile_pics/{$member_id}.png";

                            // Resize
                            $aspect_ratio = $width / $min_width;
                            $new_height = $height * $aspect_ratio;
                            $canvas1 = imagecreatetruecolor($min_width, $new_height);
                            imagecopyresampled($canvas1, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $min_width, $new_height, $width, $new_height);

                            // Crop
                            $canvas2 = imagecreatetruecolor($min_width, $min_height);
                            imagecopyresampled($canvas2, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $min_width, $min_height, $min_width, $min_height);
                            imagejpeg($canvas2, $imgPath, 80);
                            imagedestroy($canvas1);

                        }
```

I realise that there this question has been asked before, but for some reason I can't seem to make my own script work.

Comment: Does it resize it a least? Also, try setting an absolute path to the source image instead of relative.

Comment: Yes it resizes and saves correctly. The only problem is that the image goes black

Comment: You mean the resized image goes black? How is it "correctly", then?

Comment: Plus, you're initializing `$img` *after* you try to create it via `imagecreatefrompng($img)` or similar. Plus, you're trying to save `imagejpeg()` result into a file with PNG extension.

Comment: "Correctly" meaning it is saved on the server, but no the image is not correct as, it is black.. But yes you are right about the fact that i'm initializing $img too late. I don't know how I could make such a mistake.. Anyways thanks a lot. You can create an answer if you want, so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing `$img` after you try to create it via `imagecreatefrompng($img)` or similar. Might be the reason why it fails.

I'm also not sure you want to save all your images into a *.png file, regardless of their source type: you might want to implement something more flexible instead.